# Как в LyX использовать параметры в окружениях?

Tags: latex, lyx

Листая составные мануала по Lyx, я довольно часто встречаю такие места:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И каждый раз мне становится интересно, как это получают?

Answer (score 0):

Давайте я покажу это на примере окружения *Нумерация*. Аргументом в пользу выбора этого окружения явилось то, что для использования параметров в этом окружении в LyX мне потребуется в LyX использовать *модуль Customtable Lists (enumitem)*, а, значит, отвлекаясь от этого конкретного модуля, я смогу показать еще и как использовать какой угодно модуль в этой программе. Итак, для начала подключим этот модуль. Для этого идем в **Документ>Настройки>Модули**. Там, перемещая бегунок в полосе прокрутки в окошечке под словом *Доступные* ищем это словосочетание. Должен признаться, что, когда узнав, как это делается, я это записывал, я пользовался LyX'ом, установленным выполнением одного `.ехе`-шника, а сейчас у меня установлен LyX выполнением другого `.ехе`-шника, так что, когда я сейчас полез с поиском этого модуля в соответствующее место, я этот модуль там не обнаружил. Однако, открыв файл `.lyx`, изготовленный, когда я выяснил, как это делать, чтобы не забыть и, покопавшись в уже подключенных модулях, я обнаружил, что один из таких подключенных модулей - модуль *Настраиваемые списки(enumitem)*. А всего в том файле `.lyx` 3 подключенных модуля. Остальные 2 - это *Нумерация формул по разделам* и *Нумерация рисунков по разделам*. Ни один из этих модулей явно не является модулем, подключенным мной тогда с целью оказания влияния на окружение *Нумерация*. Остается только модуль *Настраиваемые списки(enumitem)*. Получается, что модуль, который в той копии LyX назывался *Customtable Lists (enumitem)*, в этой копии называется *Настраиваемые списки(enumitem)*. Будем иметь это ввиду. Итак, в окошечке под словом *Доступные* - под тем словом, как добраться до которого, я рассказал, - ищем модуль с одним из двух этих имен, щелкаем по этому модулю левой кнопкой мыши, нажимаем кнопку *Добавить*, расположенную чуть правее этого всего и нажимаем кнопку *ОК* или *Применить*. Все, нужный модуль подключен. Отмечу, что при подключении этого модуля становится доступным новое окружение. Сейчас оно у меня называется *Нумерация-Продолжение*. Чтобы в него перейти, как обычно, щелкаю левой кнопкой мыши выпадающий список окружений (ну, там, где при создании нового файла `.lyx` обычно видно слово *Обычный*), наводим мышку на элемент этого списка *Нумерация-Продолжение* и щелкаем по этому элементу левой кнопкой мышки. Суть этого окружения в том, что, если я его где-нибудь начну, напишу некоторое число пунктов этой нумерации, потом прерву чем-то эту нумерацию, например, обычным текстом, а потом опять начну это же, *Нумерация-Продолжение*, окружение, то нумерация в получающемся `.pdf` после прерывания начнется не с 1, а продолжит прерванную нумерацию (но в самом окне программы LyX нумерация по-прежнему с 1, только пункты этой нумерации, как до, так и после прерывания отличаются синим, ну, может, голубым, цветом). Впрочем, я отвлекся. Итак, Подключили названный выше модуль, начали окружение *Нумерация*. Далее, идем в меню **Вставка**. Там стал активным пункт *Краткое заглавие*. Вот по нему щелкаем левой кнопкой мыши и в появившийся прямоугольник вводим нужные нам опции в данном случае *Нумерации*, а вообще окружения, в котором это все происходит. Например, вставив такую опцию

```
start=4
```

получим соответствующую нумерацию в `.pdf`, начинающуюся не с 1, а с 4. Вообще, про опции, значение которых для окружения *Нумерация* имеет смысл указывать, в том числе описанным здесь способом можно прочитать (а не прочитать - так догадаться) в документации к пакету enumitem (я имею ввиду реализацию TeX'a - MiKTeX. Про TeXlive не знаю, рвать, ой, врать, врать)) не буду).